# Cannot get or update observable within component

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to use a knockout component to return a list of people and add  new people to the list.  I use the param to pass the value for the web service call.  All is fine on the load. I load several of these components all with a different params value.

However, if I want to reset a param when creating new users I cannot reset e.g. 
`this.newadminemail('')` because it says `this.newadminemail is not a function`.

What am I doing wrong is this even the correct ways to use components.

```
define(["knockout", "jsconfig", "jquery", "text!./channeladmins.html"], function(ko, jsconfig, $, channelAdminUserTemplate) {
    function channeladminuserViewModel(params) {

        this.newadminemail = ko.observable();
        this.channel = params.ref_id;
        this.usertype = ko.observable();
        this.usertypes = ko.observableArray(['channeladmin', 'user']);
        this.accesstoken = localStorage.getItem("accesstoken");
        this.permissionlist = ko.observableArray([]);

        // Get all the information
        this.loadpermissions = function(id) {
            this.jqxhr = $.getJSON(apiURL + 'adminpermissions?accesstoken=' + this.accesstoken + '&channelID=' + id, this.permissionlist);
            this.jqxhr.complete(function() {});

        }

        this.permissionlist.subscribe(function(newValue) {
            if (window.console && console.log) {
                console.log(++this.triggeredCount, "Email triggered with new value", newValue);
            }
        });

        this.newadminemail.subscribe(function(newValue) {
            if (window.console && console.log) {
                console.log(++this.triggeredCount, "user triggered with new value", newValue);
            }
        });

        this.newchanneladmin = function(email) {

            if (validateEmail(email)) {

                this.posturl = apiURL + 'adminpermissions?accesstoken=' + this.accesstoken + '&channelID=' + params.ref_id;

                this.request = $.ajax({
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: this.posturl,
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        "user_email": email,
                        "channel_id": params.ref_id,
                        "permissons": "channeladmin",
                    },
                    success: function(res) {
                        // I cannot refresh this function console says this.loadpermissions is           //not a functionsuccess.         
                        this.loadpermissions(params.ref_id);
                    },
                    error: function(res) {
                        alert(res.responseText);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
        this.loadpermissions(params.ref_id);
    }
    return {
        viewModel: channeladminuserViewModel,
        template: channelAdminUserTemplate
    };
});
```

Comment: By that point in your code, `this` probably refers to a different context than you would like it to. Use `var self = this;` to store a reference that you can use in your callbacks, or use `bind(this)` to specify which context you want the methods to run in,

Comment: Cheer's that has seemed to have sorted my problem, only the weekend wasted